# SpaceBar Character issues in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, virtual-keyboard

Im working on a virtual keyboard, but my space key is giving me some issues. When its pressed, it creates the space but it dosent physically show. When I hit a normal letter or number key, the space is now visible with the letter in front of it. The keyboard and space code are nearly identical.

```
function _keys(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    textSelect.setSelection(textSelect.length, textSelect.length);

    if(electoff.currentFrame == 2)
    {
        ajWidth(event);
    }

    if(terminalinput.currentFrame == 2)
    {
        TrWidth(null);
    }

    if (control == "on" && menu.visible == false ) 
    {
        if (! shift)
        {
            textSelect.appendText(letterButtonSmall[event.target.name]);
        }
        else
        {
            textSelect.appendText(letterButtonCaps[event.target.name]);
            shift = false; 
        }

        savedTxt = textSelect.text;
        textSelect.setSelection(textSelect.length, textSelect.length);

        if(textSelect.width <= 134.05 && textSelect == inputClips.inputTxt )
        {
            textSelect.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
            textSelect.x = 1.2;
        }

        if (textSelect.width >= 134.05 && textSelect == inputClips.inputTxt)
        {
            textSelect.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
            textSelect.x = 1.2 - (textSelect.width-134.05);
        }
    }

    textSelect.setSelection(textSelect.length, textSelect.length);

    if(electoff.currentFrame == 2)
    {
        ajWidth(event);
    }

    if(terminalinput.currentFrame == 2)
    {
        TrWidth(null);
    }

    focuser();
    strehrows3();
    _fontSize();
}


//spaces
key_space.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, spaceClickListener);
function spaceClickListener(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    strehrows3();
    textSelect.setSelection(textSelect.length,textSelect.length);
    if (electoff.currentFrame == 2)
    {
        ajWidth(null);
    }
    if (terminalinput.currentFrame == 2)
    {
        TrWidth(null);
    }
    if (control == "on" && menu.visible == false )
    {
        if (! shift)
        {
            textSelect.appendText(" ");
        }
        else
        {
            textSelect.appendText(" ");

            shift = false;
        }
        savedTxt = textSelect.text;
        textSelect.setSelection(textSelect.length,textSelect.length);
        if (textSelect.width <= 134.05 && textSelect == inputClips.inputTxt )
        {
            textSelect.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
            textSelect.x = 1.2;
        }
        if (textSelect.width >= 134.05 && textSelect == inputClips.inputTxt)
        {
            textSelect.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
            textSelect.x =  1.2-(textSelect.width-134.05);
        }
    }
    textSelect.setSelection(textSelect.length,textSelect.length);
    if (electoff.currentFrame == 2)
    {
        ajWidth(null);
    }
    if (terminalinput.currentFrame == 2)
    {
        TrWidth(null);
    }

        focuser();
        strehrows3();
        _fontSize();
}
```

Now I suspect the autoSize is responsible for my problems but I cant be sure.

Wondering on some creative fixes may work, Ive been contemplating using a blank symbol if there is such a thing.

Comment: I think you suspect correctly, you could check it with autoSize set to NONE, or maybe try adding non-breaking space. Also you could use autoSize to measure resized textfield, set it back to none and set width of the textfield as was previously read this way eveytime yo uencounter a space as last character you could adjust it by a certain value.

Comment: Is there a way to add a non-breaking space?

Comment: Char code for non-breaking space is 0xA0, so use: `textSelect.appendText(String.fromCharCode(0xA0));`